# Only using Multipart & MimePart in .Net MimeKit

Tags: c#, .net, xml, multipart, mimekit

I just started using this.

1. `Multipart objMP = new Multipart("related", {"What kind of array goes here?"});`
2. Is there a way I can write to the mimepart from a string instead of from a stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this API instead: [Multipart .ctor (String subtype)](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_Multipart__ctor_2.htm)

Or, if you want to create a multipart/related part, you can also use [MultipartRelated .ctor ()](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MultipartRelated__ctor.htm)

To answer your first question, though...

> 1- `Multipart objMP = new Multipart("related", {"What kind of array goes here?"});`

The .ctor that you are trying to figure out how to use is meant to be used like this:

```
new Multipart ("related",
    new Header ("X-Custom-Header", "value"),
    new TextPart ("plain") {
        Text = "This is some text content."
    },
    new MimePart ("application", "octet-stream") {
        FileName = "attachment.pdf",
        ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
        Content = new MimeContent (dataStream)
    });
```

Comment: XML is text-based, so you could do: `var mp = new TextPart ("xml") {  Text = string_XML };`

Comment: That will create a MIME part with a mime-type of `text/xml` with the string_XML value as the content.

Comment: I've removed the second question and answer here, since it did not seem to be an answer. Since the OP has not offered a clarification here (and is unlikely to do so) it is probably better removed.

Comment: Jeffrey, one last question, how do I add a blank line before the MIME boundary? Thanks again

Comment: Which MIME boundary?

Comment: xmlTextWriter.WriteWhitespace("\n \n"); did the job, thanks

Comment: My output in the mime file is: "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"    anyway I can capitalize the 'B' in binary?